# Method to catch upward/downward dragging of a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want to drag the table left to right and when I drag up/down the page has to move up and down.

This is for mobile device: http://draggabilly.desandro.com

So using above plugin to drag left and right but unable to swipe up/down. My requirement is when we swipe up/down on the table page has to scroll/move up and down.

Code:

```
var $draggable = $("table").Draggabilly({axis: 'x'});
```

The above code allow me to drag the table left and right. But when I swipe up/down I want page has to scroll up and down, but this is not happening.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you provided us with a code snippet so we can see a working example

Comment: Sure... I will add